# odinal regression

Tags: ordered-logit

I get an output of ordinal regression model using r. it has 3 levels but I can't understand how to interpret can you explain to me what is the meaning of 0/1 and 0/2?

[image]

here logic is the predicted variable....

```
                               Value Std. Error     t value      p value
sex                           -0.1713340  0.6552480  -0.2614796 7.937227e-01
nationality                    1.9440132  1.5624353   1.2442200 2.134186e-01
race                         -17.6845396  1.3415344 -13.1823233 1.109215e-39
religion                       6.4993120  0.7103028   9.1500582 5.690286e-20
place.of.origin               -0.1388703  0.5199239  -0.2670974 7.893942e-01
recidence.at.university.time  -0.3090342  1.2186897  -0.2535791 7.998208e-01
0|1                           -9.2347103  2.2702138  -4.0677713 4.746494e-05
1|2                           -7.8270152  2.3122740  -3.3849861 7.118186e-04
```

> 

Comment: You need to investigate why race has a coefficient which is tending to $-\infty$. Check this site for separation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what library you're using but I would assume $0|1$ to be the value of the constant term $\beta_{0[i=1]}$ for equation:

$$log~{Odds_{1|0}} = \beta_{0[i=1]} +\beta_{1}x_1 +\beta_{2}x_2 + ... +\beta_{n}x_n$$

and $1|2$ to be the value of the constant term $\beta_{0[i=2]}$ for equation:

$$log~{Odds_{2|1}} = \beta_{0[i=2]} +\beta_{1}x_1 +\beta_{2}x_2 + ... +\beta_{n}x_n$$

Due to the proportional odds assumption, $\beta_1, \beta_2, ..., \beta_n$ should be equal across all equations, that's why you only get one estimate for each of them. The constant term $\beta_{0[i]}$, however, will be different for ever base level $i$ of the ordinal response variable, and therefore has a unique estimate in every equation.

Comment: thank you very much but here I take the prediction variable has 3 levels 0, and 2

Comment: For 3 levels your model will have 2 equations, the third one being the reference level.